# Brouwer degree: product formula

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I've tried to find a question about the product formula, but I couldn't find anything that helped me. This is probably quite elementary for this site. I am trying to understand the product formula for the Brouwer degree of maps $$\overline{\Omega} \to R ^n,$$
where $\Omega $ is a bounded open subset of $ R ^n $.

I can see on https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Brouwer_degree that the product formula is given in terms of $$ deg [g, \Delta ,  C_i ] $$ but I do not know the definition of such a degree in terms of set: the only definition I have at hand is w.r.t. points. So, this is my first question:

1. What is the definition of $ deg [g, \Omega ,  C_i ] $?

But my main question is, actually, more specific.

2. In the context of https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Brouwer_degree , if g is just the inclusion $ g: \overline{\Delta} \to \mathbb{R} ^n $, what can I say about
   $$ deg [g\circ f, \Omega ,  0 ] $$
   in terms of $ deg [ f, \Omega ,  0 ] $?

I wonder if, in this case, $ deg [g\circ f, \Omega ,  0 ] = deg [ f, \Omega ,  0 ] $.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The sets $C_i$ are the connected components of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus f(\partial \Omega)$ and since $y \mapsto deg(f,\Omega,y)$ is constant on each $C_i$ it is convenient to write $deg(f,\Omega,C_i)$ for this constant. A good presentation of the degree including the product formula can be found in the book of Klaus Deimling: Nonlinear Functional Analysis, Springer (1985),

Comment: Please define your notation in such a way that readers do not have to follow an external link to understand what you are asking. For example, what does $\Omega$ represent?